# How do I compare each character in two different strings?

Tags: c, string, char, max, string-comparison

The thing that I want to do is to compare 2 strings with each other, character by character.

Example 1:

String A: Hello
String B: HelloWorld

Output: Hello

Example 2:

String A: Howdy
String B: Blowdy

Output: owdy

In the example above, even though String A has more characters than String B or vice versa, and they are both different, I would still want to output the characters on both strings that are the same. I would also want the program to stop comparing, once one of the strings that is being compared with has reached null.

I've come up with a few lines of codes that could probably do this, but I'm not too sure if I'm heading towards the right direction.

```
int main(){
  char stra[100];
  char strb[100];
  char strc[100];

  for(int i = 0; stra[i] != Null && strb[i] != Null; i++){
    if(stra[i] == strb[i]){
        strc[i] = stra[i];
    }
  }

  if (strc != NULL){
    printf(strc);
  }else{
    printf("both words do not match");
  }
}
```

Comment: `I would still want to output the characters on both strings that are the same.`-->what about this input? `A: abcdgh and B: dcbaefgh` should it output `abcdh`?

Comment: output should be gh

Comment: How can you please explain?

Comment: You are comparing uninitialized strings. And what is `Null`?

Comment: What output do you want for `ABCDEFG` and `XBXXDEFY`? `BDEF`? I think the your specification is not complete.

Answer (score 1):

We, beginners, should help each other.

The assignment is not simple as it seems.

Here you are.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void max_common_substring( const char *s1, const char *s2 )
{
    size_t max_common_length = 0;
    const char *max_start    = NULL;

    for ( ; *s1; ++s1 )
    {
        const char *p = strchr( s2, *s1 );
        if ( p != NULL )
        {
            size_t common_length = 0;
            for ( const char *q = s1; *q && *p && *q == *p; ++q, ++p )
            {
                ++common_length;                    
            }

            if ( max_common_length < common_length )
            {
                    max_common_length = common_length;
                    max_start = s1;
            }
        }
    }        

    if ( max_start != NULL )
    {
        printf( "%*.*s\n", ( int )max_common_length, ( int )max_common_length, max_start );
    }        
}

int main( void )
{
    const char *s1 = "Hello";
    const char *s2 = "HelloWorld";

    max_common_substring( s1, s2 );

    s1 = "Howdy";
    s2 = "Blowdy";

    max_common_substring( s1, s2 );
}
```

The program output is

```
Hello
owdy
```

You could optimize the loop

```
for ( ; *s1; ++s1 )
```

by stopping the loop when non processed characters left in the string `s1` are already less than the current calculated value of `max_common_length`.

As for your code in the question then it is evident that it does not make sense.:)

Comment: I'm not sure if he wants that. For me his specification is incomplete and/or unclear. Upvoted anyway.

Comment: @Jabberwocky In my opinion I have understood the assignment correctly.:)

Comment: @Jabberwocky Another approach is to return the maximum common substring allocated dynamically. But in the assignment there is written that the substring should be only outputted.:)

Answer (score 0):

The end of a string is  '\0' and not NULL, then your printf should be printf("%s\n", strc) overwise you will get an error while compiling. 
If you want to check if a character is in a sentence then you should check your first letter, compare it to all the letter of the second string, if it's in it, stock it somewhere, then you go to the second letter of your first string and you do it for all the letter of your first string. Because in this code you post, it's not what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

in C the end character of the string is `\0`, Null is use for check if a pointer is initialized. You should use printf like this : `printf("%s\n", strc);`, '%s' is use to print a string.

Answer (score -2):

The end of a string in C is a '\0' a not NULL, NULL is for a pointer which means you can use it on a string ( a char * like stra ) but not on a character ( like stra[i] ). Finally for printf you should use : printf("%s\n", strc);